# CSV file includes the current page html in the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, export-to-csv

I am creating a csvfile on click of a  using the below code but when I open the file it has the correct data along with that current page html is present.

```
private void ExportToCsvFile(List<LeadInfo> leadInfos)
        {
            const string fileName = "lead_Report.csv";

            //Convert the List to csv string
            var result = leadInfos.ToCsv();


            //Write byte[] to the response or Start downloading the file automatically
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

Any thing I am missing here. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I guess that depends on what is passed into `leadInfos`

Comment: Post your Controller action, you probably calling `return View(...)` at the end of your controller action

Comment: I am calling this in a button click in asp,net webform

Comment: seems Response.end() is the only solution as HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); is not working

Answer (score 0):

I try Response.End() instead CompleteRequest(). It work

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```